# iPad Safari / onload時にwindows.openができない。

Tags: javascript, safari

```
function test(){
  window.open("/xxxxx/TEST.PDF","_blank","");
}
:
< body onload='test();'>
:
```

iPad Safariを使用し、上記のスクリプトを実行するとPDFのPOPUP画面が開きません。
（body onloadによるwindow.openが動いてくれない。）

- PC版Safariでは、問題なく動き、PDFのPOPUP画面が開きます。
- ボタンによるクリックイベントも、PDFのPOPUP画面が開きます。
- PDFではなくHTMLファイルにしても、POPUP画面が表示されませんでした。
- safariは、最新に更新しています。
- safari設定のポップブロックは「オフ」にしています。

何か解決方法がございましたら、お教示ください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5):

自己レスです。
mobile safariの仕様との事でした。
※onloadによるwindow.openが効かないみたいです。
閲覧頂き、ありがとうございました。

※参考：http://cygx.mydns.jp/blog/?arti=475